# Get individual heights of collection of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var posts = elementToAdd.find(".post");
posts.each(function(i, e) {
    var elementHeight = e.height() // BANG!
});
```

Posts contains many matched elements, which I'm trying to loop and perform logic based on each element's height, but the individual elements don't have the height property, so how can I get around this?

Comment: Just FYI, you're missing an ending `)` after the last `}`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) is a jQuery method, to use it create a jQuery object from the element.

```
var posts = elementToAdd.find(".post");
posts.each(function(i, e) {
    var elementHeight = $(e).height();
});
```

Also take a look at [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

Comment: I recommend to use `.outerHeight()` if you need the *real height* including the border and padding of the element.

Comment: This no longer errors, but always returns `0` (`height` or `outerHeight`).

Comment: It might be because they are elements on an off page DOM. I'll post another question.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett are you sure the height isn't actually 0.

Comment: @Musa: Yes, the inner html looks fine and if I just add the elements with no logic they display on the page fine (although not where I want them, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

each and height are JQuery functionality.
Make sure you have a JQuery reference on your page and try this:

```
$('.post').each(
    function(ix, val) {
        var elementHeight = $(val).height();
        // more stuff...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use .height() jquery function...

http://api.jquery.com/height/

CODES..

```
var posts = elementToAdd.find(".post");
posts.each(function(i, e) {
    var elementHeight = $(e).height();  // calculate the height of current element.
}
```